# CMake: incorrect compilation order: generate_protobuf_cpp in submodule

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers

Project structure:

```
/
|--- src/
     |--- *.cpp
|--- CMakeLists.txt (root)
|--- vendor/
     |--- submodule
          |--- protos
               |--- message.proto
          |--- src
               |--- *.cpp (#include "message.pb.h")
          |--- CMakeLists.txt (submodule)
```

`CMakeLists.txt` (submodule):

```
##################################
# Message protos
##################################
protobuf_generate_cpp(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS protos/message.proto)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

##################################
# submodule
##################################
include_directories(src/)
set(submodule_SRC src/foobar.cpp ${PROTO_SRCS} ${PROTO_HDRS})
add_library(submodule STATIC ${submodule_SRC})
target_link_libraries(goboard ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES})
set(submodule_INCLUDE_DIR ${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} PARENT_SCOPE)
```

`CMakeLists.txt` (root)

```
add_subdirectory(${root_SOURCE_DIR}/vendor/submodule)
include_directories(${submodule_INCLUDE_DIR})

# And other sources...
```

The submodule itself compiles well. But when I include it as a submodule of root project. `make -j4` would yield:

```
vendor/submodule/foobar.cpp: fatal error: 'message.pb.h' file not found
#include "message.pb.h"
```

Strangely, if I run `make -j4` again after it failed, `[ 33%] Running C++ protocol buffer compiler on src/protos/message.proto` would be called correctly and binary could be generated without any problem. `make -j2` or `make` will not face this problem.

Guess the reason might be wrong source dependency, but how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If this snippet is from submodule CMakeLists.txt, shouldn't protobuf line be

```
protobuf_generate_cpp(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS protos/message.proto)
```

If you have that line in parent CMakeLists.txt, then this is probably the source of the problem. Documentation for [FindProtobuf.cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindProtobuf.html) states

> The protobuf_generate_cpp and protobuf_generate_python functions and add_executable() or add_library() calls only work properly within the same directory.

Comment: Proto path is a typo. Is there any way(or workaround) to use `protobuf_generate_cpp` in nested project?

Comment: @lz96 Not I am aware of.